# Getting SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request error

Tags: python, salesforce, integration

I am trying to execute this following code to push data to Salesforce using the `simple_salesforce` python library :

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

staging_df = hive.execute("select * from hdmni")
staging_df = staging_df.toPandas()
# # staging_df['birth_date']=  staging_df['birth_date'].dt.date
staging_df['birth_date'] = staging_df['birth_date'].astype(str)
staging_df['encounter_start_date'] = staging_df['encounter_start_date'].astype(str)
staging_df['encounter_end_date'] = staging_df['encounter_end_date'].astype(str)

bulk_data = []

for row in staging_df.itertuples():
    d= row._asdict()
    del d['Index']
    bulk_data.append(d)

sf = Salesforce(password='', username='', security_token='')
sf.bulk.Delivery_Detail__c.insert(bulk_data)
```

I am getting this error while trying to send dictionary to salesforce :

> SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request
>   https://subhotutorial-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/async/38.0/job/7500o00000HtWP6AAN/batch/7510o00000Q15TnAAJ/result.
>   Response content: {'exceptionCode': 'InvalidBatch',
>   'exceptionMessage': 'Records not processed'}

Comment: What are the field names in Salesforce? Custom fields in Salesforce end with `__c`. For instance instead of a `birth_date` field in your `Delivery_Detail__c` object, it would be called `Birth_Date__c`. Same thing with `Encounter_Start_Date__c` and `Encounter_End_Date__c`.

Comment: Glad to hear. Have converted to an answer with more details and context.

Answer (score 3):

There's something about your query that is not correct. While I don't know your use case, by reading this line, you can tell that you are attempting to insert into a custom object/entity in Salesforce:

```
sf.bulk.Delivery_Detail__c.insert(bulk_data)
```

The reason you can tell is because of the `__c` suffix, which gets appended onto custom objects and fields (that's two underscores, by the way).

Since you're inserting into a custom object, your fields would have to be custom, too. And note, you've not appended that suffix onto them.

> **Note**: Every custom object/entity in Salesforce does come with a few standard fields to support system features like record key (`Id`), record name (`Name`), audit fields (`CreatedById`, `CreatedDate`, etc.). These wouldn't have a suffix. But none of the fields you reference are any of these standard system fields...so the `__c` suffix would be expected.

I suspect that what Salesforce is expecting in your insert operation are field names like this:

```
Birth_Date__c
Encounter_Start_Date__c
Encounter_End_Date__c
```

These are referred to as the *API name* for both objects and fields, and anytime code interacts with them (whether via integration, or on code that executes directly on the Salesforce platform) you need to make certain you're using this API name.

Incidentally, you can retrieve this API name through a number of ways. Probably easiest is to log into your Salesforce org, and in **Setup > Object Manager > [some object] > Fields and Relationships** you can view details of each field, including the API name. Here's a screen shot.

[image: Field definition in Setup UI]

You can also use SObject describe APIs, either in native Apex code, or via integration and either the [REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm) or [SOAP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm) APIs. Here's part of the response from the describe API request to the describe REST endpoint for the same object as my UI example above, found here at `https://[domain]/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Expense__c/describe`:

[image: SObject Field Describe Response]

Looking at the docs for the simple-salesforce python library you're using, they've surfaced the describe API. You can find some [info](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/#other-options) under *Other Options*. You would invoke it as *sf.SObject.describe* where "SObject" is the actual object you want to find the information about. For instance, in your case you would use:

```
sf.Delivery_Detail__c.describe()
```

As a good first troubleshooting step when interacting with a Salesforce object, I'd always recommend double-checking correctly referencing an API name. I can't tell you how many times I've bumped into little things like adding or missing an underscore. Especially with the `__c` suffix.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed post! Yet, I'd say it is outdated regarding the current SalesForce interface. Moreover, I don't think that you need to append `__c` to all fields within a Custom Object. These fields could be well-defined standard fields which are interlinked with your Custom Object.

Comment: You're right. There are certain standard fields that are implicitly created on custom objects to support system features like `Name`, `CreatedBy`, `IsDeleted`, etc. My point above was primarily to support my assertion that he was missing the custom field suffix. Since the needed fields were none of these implicitly created standard fields, by elimination, he was referencing custom fields. But I can try to capture that nuance.